# Changing opacity of other element on hover, using jQuery in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to change the opacity of other elements on a hover using jQuery on my Wordpress site.

Here is an example:
http://www.casinotitan.im/ (firefox gives the best result)

```
<div class="container">

<div class="example">
    <img src="example.png" alt=".." class="img-example" />
</div>

<div class="example">
    <img src="example.png" alt=".." class="img-example" />
</div>

<div class="example">
    <img src="example.png" alt=".." class="img-example" />
</div>
```

I also want to insert this script into a Wordpress page (my homepage),
but I don't understand what the procedure is to get jQuery up and running.

Comment: Include the jquery file in your header locally (your theme folder is obtained by **<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>**) or include **<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>** in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
$(".example").hover(function() {
    $(".example").not($(this)).toggleClass("translucent");
});
```

CSS:

```
.translucent {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

You can see it in action at: http://jsfiddle.net/sUnh8/1/

Check the comment by @maxzeroedge on how to get jQuery up and running.